# Enemy worthy of Lady Shiva

Tags: dc, batman

Following the events of Nightfall, Batman had somehow recovered from the back breaker (HOW!?) and asked Lady Shiva to retrain him since he's been out of action to long. She does this by killing an armless martial arts master (who was incredibly good ), framing it on Bruce ( who was using an entirely different persona at the time), and letting his former students try to violently murder Bruce and test him on how he defeats them.

My question is: who is the armless master that came close to defeating Lady Shiva?

Comment: Bruce's back is dealt with in [*Knightquest: The Search*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Knightquest#Knightquest:_The_Search). Short version: because magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is only named [the Armless Master](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Armless_Master_%28New_Earth%29). He is the brother of [the Legless Master](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Legless_Master_(New_Earth)). DC hasn't revealed any additional information past that the two of them used to fight on the Thai fighting circuits.